# Editing lists with foreach in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Apologies if this is a really stupid question.

If I have a model with a list in it, like:

```
public class Edit_model
{
    public List<Other_model> Items { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Default class constructor
    /// </summary>
    public RecipesEdit_model()
    {
        this.Items = new List<Other_Model>();
    }
}
```

And I pass this to my `Edit` action, populate `Items` and then send it off to the View. Since `Items` is a list, I always try to do something like this:

```
        <div>
            <ul>
                @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
                {
                    <li>
                        @Html.EditorFor(m => item, "_ItemEditorTemplate")
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Which always screws up the ids of the controls generated in the template, so model binding on the `Edit` post action never works.

It does work if I loop through `Items` using a `for` loop though, like this:

```
        <div>
            <ul>
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    <li>
                        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Items[i], "_ItemEditorTemplate")
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
```

I can see why that works, because I get the lambda expression actually using the correct variable in the function... but I don't like this much, because from experience programming in C# you can get indexing issues, so I'd much rather use `foreach`.

What is the syntax to make this work with `foreach`?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => item, "_ItemEditorTemplate")
```

It is right.

m just a variable, not actually use it in the method body.

what is error message?

Comment: Thanks for answering. There's no error message, but the ids of the input tags generated that way are with reference to the block variable, so binding doesn't work. It only works when using a for block an accessing the properties by index.